# Connect Paypal payments to Cloudbeds booking engine

Tags: paypal

I want to connect paypal with my cloudbeds dashboard so that i can start receiving payments through
cloudbeds booking engine

I hav already added the paypal details in the cloudbeds payment options

Comment: Read cloudbeds documentation and/or contact them for support, not a programming nor software development question